# Как сохранить разделитель при разделении строки с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть задача из строки сделать список, где 1 элемент - все буквы до 1 не буквы, а второй элемент все что после. Включая эту первую не букву.
Пример на входе `'ddd?.rt/ffff'` на выходе `['ddd', '?.rt/ffff']`

Выражение    `re.split(r'(^\w+)', 'ddd?.rt/ffff' , maxsplit=1)` дает на выходе -

```
['', 'ddd', '?.rt/ffff'].
```

Вопрос. Что с этим выражением сделать чтоб не генерировался пустой элемент?
Ну и если только буквы скормить этому выражению, то генерируются 2 пустых элемента по краям списка. Они тоже не нужны. Спасибо.

Comment: Забыл написать. Хотелось бы сделать это split()ом, а не дополнительной командой/циклом.

Comment: Вот так - re.split(r'([a-zA-Z]+)(.*)', input_string)   А если напрягают пустые элементы списка по краям - то re.match, а затем group().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
[ i for i in re.split(r'(^\w+)', 'ddd?.rt/ffff') if i]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while '' in list:
    list.remove('')
```